# Chrome debug tools for react native: multiple issues

Tags: react-native

thanks in advance your your help; I rather a newbie with RN and Android (i used create-native init to create project).

Issue 1: when i first <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and choose "Debug JS Remotely" it attempts [http://10.0.2.2:8081/debugger-ui] but hangs indefinitely.

Issue 2. and when I finally give up and instead manually visit [http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/], I have no way to revert AVD from "white screen of death"..ive tried "Stop Remote JS Bebugging", "Reload" etc....but end of having to use "react-native run-android" to refresh

Issue 3: Once I finally have [http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/] displaying the desired "Debugger session #0 active" and I go into dev tools --> Sources --> Network --> debuggerWorker.js.....I don't see my folders/files listed.  See screenshot.

RN is hard enough without being able to debug!

[image]

Comment: Why can no-one answer this?

Comment: No answer to #3 is killing me...I really want to be able to debug.

Comment: Ill give $50 to whoever can answer #3

Comment: I got the exactly same 3 issue as you had, and did some searching. Here is the bug, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18416

Answer (score 11):

This solution worked for me:

1. `ctrl+m` on your emulator.
2. click on `Dev Settings`.
3. Disable `User JS Delta`
4. restart the react native server. (ctrl+c in the terminal and then `npm run android`)

Answer (score 8):

This is an issue with the of latest version of react-native (0.54).

After some investigation, I found there are two ways to workaround this issue.

#### Option 1. Downgrade react versions, modify the package.json of your AwesomeProject as below

```js
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.52.2"
},
```

Then run these commands:

```sh
cd AwesomeProject
rm -rf node_modules android
npm install # this will bring folder node_modules back, with react/react-native of previous version
react-native eject # this will bring folder android back
react-native run-android
```

#### Option 2. Turning off `Use JS Deltas` as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18416)

But the author did not provide full steps, which led me working out option 1.

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> in your emulator, and turn off "Use JS Deltas".
2. Find the termnial window for "Metro Bundler", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to terminate it, then press the Up arrow to re-run the command for "Metro Bundler", such as `/works/StackOverflow/node_modules/react-native/scripts/launchPackager.command ; exit;`. (**This is an important step**).

Now back to Chrome, you can find your source files listed under `debuggerWorker.js` > `localhost:8081`.

[image]

Comment: I have the full path being shown in my file/folder under localhost:8081.
E.g. 
http://localhost:8081/C:\Users\xxxxxx\React_native_practical_tutorial\App.js
... Has anyone facing this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue , manage to fix it by going setting inside inspect element and enable the javascript

[image: Screenshot]