# React Native Chrome Debugger

Tags: react-native

Anyone know where Im supposed to find my js files in the Chrome debugger?
They dont appear to be anywhere?

[image]

Comment: If you are using `Mac`, then use `COMMAND + P`, then type your file name.

Comment: Seems like there is a problem building your `sourcemaps`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome debug tools for react native: mutiple issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340074/chrome-debug-tools-for-react-native-mutiple-issues)